# Problems with mount command while mounting an image file

Tags: 12.04, mount, iso

I have a local site for accessing data on virtual drives. To do so I created a few directories inside my /var/www/ and a simle html file to access the starting pdf or htm* files on those virtual drives that are intended to be used as local catalogs on CD/DVD. I also must say, file that is being mounted is on a NTFS partition.

```
cd /   
sudo mount "/media/Video/Virtual Drives/file.iso" /var/www/dest_folder
```

First time when I enter it, I get an error that the source location does not exist, but when I use file browser to go to the /media/Video/Virtual Drives/ folder. After the visit command functiones.

When I entered all the mount commands manualy that was not a big problem, but now I created a sh script for seven differnt iso files and insterted it in init.d to automaticly start, now I have a problem because the script does not work.

Ubuntu version is 12.04LTS

Can you help?

Regards,
SaleB

Comment: is /media/video/virtual drives itself a mount ? If so you need to use the second mount AFTER

Comment: Yes, that was primary problem, when I added the ntfs partition into  fstab, everything started working

Comment: added it as an answer

Answer (score 3):

Use the following command, plus escape the whitespace:

`mount -o loop /media/Video/Virtual\ Drives/file.iso /var/www/dest_folder`

If i recall correctly you need the `loop` option, i have never tried it without that option.

**Update:**

Or add the following to `/etc/fstab` to automount on startup, since that is the thing you actually need.

`/media/Video/Virtual\ Drives/file.iso /var/www/dest_folder iso9660 loop,ro,auto 0 0`

*hth*

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Yes it is a loop virtual path. I will try it tomorrow.
I have found a part of the problem why it did not work. I have inserted the ntfs partition into /etc/fstab and now all works. I have added the sh file into some folder in /etc/ and now all works fine. After a restart I have all loop drives visible form /var/www/

Comment: But there is in commands no more sudo because those sh files in that folder already execute with root privileges

Comment: You can mount the iso directly using the `/etc/fstab`. That way you don't have to invoke some script manually when starting up. I have updated my answer. Just use `mount -a` after you added the iso, to mount all the entries described in `/etc/fstab`.

Answer (score 2):

you need to escape spaces in path

`sudo mount "/media/Video/Virtual\ Drives/file.iso" /var/www/dest_folder`

Comment: Why? - IOW: please elaborate why the additional escaping is needed, even though the file is already between quotation marks `"`.

Comment: spaces in paths must always be escaped by \ in commandline, an easy way of handling this is using the autocomplete function of the commandline by using the tab-Key the "" have on effect on the escaping of spaces

Comment: That's not true. If you autocomplete with `"` in bash it will do it without backslashes - and it will work.

Comment: In fact the additional backslashes here are needed because of the use of `sudo`. Running `sudo cmd "file\ text"` will make the space go correctly the cmd after sudo has switched.

Comment: you are right! shame on me!

Comment: The intentation of my comments where to have you update your answer. Go ahead I'll upvote, if an explanation is present.

Comment: I do not find a proper explanation for this issue. The recommended way of passing arguments is without quotes like @ortang mentioned is his answer. If anyone else is able to explain I am highly interested in an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

is /media/video/virtual drives itself a mount ? If so you need to use the second mount after this folder has been mounted successfully